# No intropage in a Managed Windows Service

Tags: wcf

I have to do some maintenance on a WCF service that is hosted in a managed windows service.

In the old deployed version I can enter: http://localhost:9091. It shows a page with info about the hosted WCF service (with a C# and VB example).

When I get the sources from TFS and reinstall with the MSI, the same http://localhost:9091 gives a 404.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be lots of things. Try these for a start:

- Installed msi on wrong port
- web site / app pool not runnig
- the configuration in web.config does not match the new location
- Web site not marked as asp.net 2.0
- IIS not configured to recognise svc files

The last 3 are the most probable. Check the event log for more details.

Here are a few more based on the comment:

- is the service started
- is the port blocked on the new machine
- the configuration in web.config does not match the new location

Comment: This is a WCF service hosted in a managed windows service, not IIS

Comment: It was a configuration endpoint mismatch: the namespace was wrong... pfff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that port is meant to be the port of the ASP.NET Development Server. Is the service started? Open the solution in Visual Studio, right-click the service and choose "View in browser". That will have the side-effect of starting the service.